# Helm, Is there a way to add kubernetes labels to values.yaml (without using template and _helpers.tpl)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

So as in the title, I would like to add labels to my helms of my already running applications (sonarqube and jenkins from official helm charts).
I don't have templates in them just values.yaml. I am afraid of adding templates, because as I said, application is already running and I just want to add few labels in metadata.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  There's not really standard structure to the `values.yaml` file, so it would depend on how the templates are using the values there.

Comment: I was using for example: 
https://github.com/Oteemo/charts/tree/master/charts/sonarqube and 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/jenkins
and even if they have default labels, I want to add my own

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both charts mentioned in comment under question has a way to define custom labels

https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/jenkins/templates/jenkins-master-deployment.yaml#L42

```
    {{- range $key, $val := .Values.master.podLabels }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $val | quote }}
    {{- end}}
```

https://github.com/Oteemo/charts/blob/master/charts/sonarqube/templates/deployment.yaml#L31

```
{{- with .Values.podLabels }}
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
```

So you need something like this in `values.yaml`

```
# Jenkins
master:
  podLabels:
    label1Name: label1Value

# Sonar
podLabels:
  label1Name: label1Value
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found deployment labels in jenkins chart:
`master.deploymentLabels`
but is there an option to add it to sonarqube?
or in other case when it will not be present as an option in values, to somehow overwrite metadata?

Comment: @rkosegi I'm facing a similar issue in `nfs-server-provisioner` chart. They don't have this build in and the other answer by @mark is not working since I'm using tilt. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

As described by [@rkosegi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352290/11207414) this solution uses best practices while working with k8s configurations.

Please keep in mind, that users always should store configuration files ([Configuration Best Practices](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#general-configuration-tips)). It allows us to quickly change/roll back any configuration in an easy way, using:

```
    kubectl apply -f ...
    kubectl replace ...
```

---

Another solutions:

- **[kubectl edit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#edit) deployment** <deployment_name>
- **[Update API Objects in Place Using kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)**:

---

**a**) adding or changing existing labels:

```
#patch-file.yaml
```

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        test: label
```

```
kubectl patch deployment <deployment-name>  --patch "$(cat patch-file.yaml)"
```

**b**) using a json patch approach, you can:

- **add** one **new label** "**NewTest**" with **value** "**TestValue**":

```
kubectl patch deployment <deployment-name>  --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/metadata/labels/NewTest", "value":"TestValue"}]'
```

- **replace** **label** "**NewTest**" with **value** "**OldTest**":

```
kubectl patch deployment <deployment-name>  --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/metadata/labels/NewTest", "value": "OldTest"}]'
```

- **remove label** "**NewTest**":

```
kubectl patch deployment <deployment-name>  --type='json' -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/metadata/labels/NewTest"}]'
```

---

Additional informations:

- [JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902)
- [kubectl patch reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch)